# OpenShift 4.2 Rest API documentation

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-enterprise

Is there any link to find OpenShift 4.2 Rest API documentation?
I could see latest that we have is for 3.11
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/rest_api/index.html.

Answer (score 4):

Will is absolutely right, and here is the link to doco:

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.3/rest_api/index.html

When in doubt, this command is your best friend

oc --loglevel=9

Answer (score 2):

OpenShift Rest API documentation is expected to be available once 4.3 is released. In the meantime, OpenShift 4.2 is built on top of Kubernetes 1.14; the 1.14 Rest API documentation is available at https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/.

For OpenShift specific resources, if you're looking for the resource definitions, you can use `oc explain <RESOURCE> --recursive` from the cli to see a full resource definition.