# Why rest api is not upgrade from 3.x to 4.x in openshift?

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-enterprise

Why rest API is not upgrade from 3.11 version to 4.2 version in openshift?

Comment: Ask your problem in details not in one line. So users can understand your problem.

Comment: My question is that till Openshift 3.11 its having the rest API available as I got it from the below URL
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/upgrading/automated_upgrades.html

But for Openshift 4.1/4.2 rest API is not there and I have not found any reference for it
So I am asking the reason behind it why it is not available in 4.1/4.2 version of openshift. 
Why, rest API is not up-gradable in higher version of openshift?

Comment: Edit your question and paste the above code.

Comment: If your asking about Rest API docs, that question was just asked last week: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58625409/openshift-4-2-rest-api-documentation

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question and the 4.X docs will be released next release.

[Here](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-docs/issues/17727) is the answer I received from the maintainers of the OpenShift docs.

Answer (score 0):

The Explore tab along the left menu in 4.x cluster console contains the API documentation for all API objects.

[image: See here]